# ARP requests sent on different subnets

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping, wireshark, arp

I am quite confused with an experiment I made at home. I have two computers, say **A** and **B**:

- **A** and **B** are connected (ethernet) to the same private network (with a gateway to the internet) 192.168.1.99/24 (**A**) and 192.168.1.7/24 (**B**)
- **B** is configured as a wifi access point (different subnet 192.168.2.254/24) but with no DHCP server

If client **A** wifi connection is configured manually with 192.168.2.1/24, I can ping **B** from the wifi interface. This is the expected behaviour. However, if **A** wifi connection is kept with DHCP configuration, I can still ping **B** on the wifi interface although **A** does not even got an IP.

```
guest@A ~ $ ping -I wlp5s0 192.168.2.254
ping: Warning: source address might be selected on device other than wlp5s0.
PING 192.168.2.254 (192.168.2.254) from 192.168.1.99 wlp5s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=6.86 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.254: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.26 ms
```

Obviously, ICMP paquets are sent from wifi interface **A** using ethernet IP of **A** wifi IP of **B**. Sniffing with wireshark, I noticed the following:

- ARP request is broadcasted from **A** wifi interface with sender IP 192.168.1.99 and target IP 192.168.2.254
- ARP reply on the same interface
- ICPMs on that interface with source IP 192.168.1.99 and dest IP 192.168.2.254

Why did **A** send an ARP request to discover MAC address of **B** and not of its default gateway since it is not, supposedly, in its network. Maybe for **A** on the wifi interface, as no IP/subnet has been defined, another IP is used with unset/0.0.0.0 subnet ?!